# Why EFContextProvider 1.4.16 throws DbUpdateConcurrencyException when trying to update Enum value?

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to save a single change - an enum property value update.  EFContextProvider.SaveChanges() is called on the server, but generated SQL is wrong and when executed by the EFContextProvider it throws System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

The enum property is defined like this:

```
        public virtual System.Nullable<StanZleceniaOplaty> Stan { get; set; }

        public enum StanZleceniaOplaty : int
        {
                    Created,
                    Started,
                    Canceled,
                    Rejected,
                    Paid
        }
```

EntityTypeConfiguration for entity ZlecenieOplaty configures Stan with the following code:

```
        this
            .Property(p => p.Stan)
                .IsConcurrencyToken()
                .HasColumnType("int");
```

Please note that this enum property **IsConcurrencyToken**.

I'm changing the enum from Created to Canceled and calling SaveChanges().
I can see that the SQL generated by EFContextProvider agains the EF 6.1 DB is wrong ([Stan] is not changed, because @0 == @2, @2 has wrong value - should be 0).

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[ZlecenieOplaty]
SET [Stan] = @0
WHERE (([Id] = @1) AND ([Stan] = @2))
SELECT [NrZlecenia]
FROM [dbo].[ZlecenieOplaty]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = @1',
N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int',
@0=2,
@1=3,
@2=2
```

In effect the following exception is thrown.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at Alcance.Entities.AlcanceDbContext.SaveChanges() in d:\Develop\alcance\src\dev\Alcance.Data\Model\AlcanceModel.AlcanceDbContext.Connection.cs:line 121
  InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
       Source=EntityFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       InnerException:
```

I opened https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/issues/8.

Can anybody confirm that this is a bug?

Comment: I would recommend putting relevant code here as well so someone could easily see if there is a problem somewhere.

Comment: I updated my question with more details and code.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. Are you using an Enum property as a concurrency column and if so why???.  The idea of a concurrency column is to handle optimistic concurrency collisions, and to use an enum value for such a case seems wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'm using an Enum property as a concurrency column. This column represents the state of the entity. I know, that usually RowVersion is used, but in this particular case I'm interested only in concurrency collisions caused by state change. I may decide to switch to RowVersion later.